# how to end interact in expect on specific output?

Tags: linux, automation, expect

I am trying to exit interact in expect when certain text appear on screen anywhere.

The intended functionality from the code below is to exit interact if "Press any key" appears anywhere on the screen (-o).

However it's not working. Any idea what is the correct way to do this ?

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f


spawn program
# do stuff
interact  {

-o "*Press any key to continue*" {

send "^]"
send -- "7\r"
return
   }
}

# do more stuff

expect eof
```

Comment: why do you `send` in `-o { ... }`? whats your purpose? and do you mean `CTRL ]` with `^]`?

Comment: it's not required. I was just trying different way. it doesn't work with or without sends there.

with ^] I need the ESC key. but it's not required, could be out side the interact after control return to expect.

Answer (score 4):

According to `man expect`, for `interact`:

> **By default, string matching is exact with no wild cards.** (In contrast, the `expect` command uses glob-style patterns by default.)

To match a pattern, you need to use `-re` <sup>(`-gl` is not supported)</sup>.

```
[STEP 101] $ cat foo.exp
proc expect_prompt {} {
    upvar spawn_id spawn_id
    expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+[#$] $}
}

spawn bash --noprofile --norc
expect -re {bash-[.0-9]+[#$] $}

set flag 0
interact {
    -o
    -re "LET.*OUT" {
        send_user $interact_out(0,string)
        set flag 1
        return
    }
}
expect_prompt

if { $flag } {
    send "echo Do something\r"
    expect_prompt
}

send "exit\r"
expect eof
[STEP 102] $
```

Result:

```
[STEP 103] $ expect foo.exp
spawn bash --noprofile --norc
bash-5.1$ echo let me out | tr a-z A-Z    # <-- manual input
LET ME OUT
bash-5.1$ echo Do something
Do something
bash-5.1$ exit
exit
[STEP 104] $
```

By the way, to send an <kbd>ESC</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl [</kbd>), use `send "\x1b"`.